# XCode is bugging out when adding an initialisation function from an Objective-C based Cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm running the following code in my ViewController based on a cocoapod that is written in Objective-C:

```
    myCountDownTimer.setupCountDownForTheFirstTime(
        { (timer:ZGCountDownTimer) -> void in
        timer.totalCountDownTime = 10
        },
        restoreFromBackUp: { (timer:ZGCountDownTimer) -> Void in
        println ("its not running anymore")
    });
```

I translated it (I think correctly) from Objective-C which looked like this:

```
[self.myCountDownTimer setupCountDownForTheFirstTime:^(ZGCountDownTimer *timer) {
    timer.totalCountDownTime = kDefaultCountDownTime;
}                                  restoreFromBackUp:^(ZGCountDownTimer *timer) {
    //some code
}];
```

It returns no code errors, but XCode starts bugging out (eg all my code changes to white) and I get a message at the top of the screen saying *"Xcode encountered a problem, source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore..."*

Then when I try build, I get the compile error *Swift Compile Error "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"*

I comment that segment of code out and the issue ceases.

Thanks in advance.